# How to use an exception class, catch and handle the exception in main program

Tags: java, exception

I have a program that accepts information from the user about a game object and then writes the array of game objects to a file. I also need to use an exception class I created. If the user inputs a document code other than Sp, St, or Gh, an exception needs to be thrown then caught and handled, allowing the user to try entering a proper code. I think my exception class is correct, but I don't really know how to implement it.

```
public class InvalidDocumentCodeException extends Exception //Here is my exception class
{     
    public InvalidDocumentCodeException (String message)   
    { 
      super (message);       
    } 
}

import  java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class  GamesList  
{   
  public static void  main (String[] args) throws InvalidDocumentCodeException, IOException     
  {      
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
    int count = 0, year;
    String doMore = "y"; 
    String file = "GameInfo.dat";
    String documentCode, title, developer;
    double price;

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (file);     
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);     
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (bw);

    //don't know if I need this
    InvalidDocumentCodeException problem = new InvalidDocumentCodeException ("Incorrect document code!!!");

    GameCollection games = new GameCollection();

    while (doMore.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) //lets user input data until they are done
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a valid document code (Sp, St, Gh):");
      documentCode = scan.nextLine();

      try     //my try catch
      {
        documentCode = "Sp";
      }
      catch(InvalidDocumentCodeException)
      {
        System.out.println("Oops! Try a valid code:");
        documentCode = scan.nextLine();
      }

      System.out.println("Enter the game name:");
      title = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter the game developer:");
      developer = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter the games release year:");
      year = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the games price:");
      price =  scan.nextDouble();

      games.addGame(documentCode, title, developer, year, price);

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("This is great. Let's enter some more data. (Y/N):");

      doMore = scan.next();
      scan.nextLine();

      }
    outFile.println(games);
    System.out.println("Data written to GameInfo.dat");

    System.out.println(games);
    outFile.close();
  }
}
```

I've looked around, but maybe I'm just not understanding how exceptions and try catch statement work well enough.

Comment: Where do you think the main method is going to throw the error to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you create and throw the exception when and where you need to.  So, for instance, you could so something like:

```
try {
  // Do something
  if (somethingIsWrong) {
    throw new MyException("This is broke, yo!");
  }
} catch(MyException me) {
  // Write code to handle the exception or log it...
}
```

The other way to do it is to call something that throws an exception:

```
try {
  callToMethodThatThrowsSomeException(someVal);
} catch(SomeException se) {
  // Handle the exception here...
}
```

Where `callToMethodThatThrowsSomeException(someVal)` would look like:

```
public void callToMethodThatThrowsSomeException(String someVal) throws SomeException {
  // Your code here, throwing a new SomeException for some reason...
}
```

In this case, `SomeException` would extend `Exception`.  You could make it extend `RuntimeException` instead, in which case you dont need to declare the throws on the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

When a method throws an exception the calling method must have a catch statement.

In this case, there is no method invoking the main method, so the the throw will give a stacktrace in stderr without you ever getting a chance to handle the exception.

If you want to do error checking in the main method use a try-catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You're not throwing the exception e.g. your specification says

> If the user inputs a document code other than Sp, St, or Gh

and that means you need code like(for example):

```
if (!isValidGameCode(documentCode)) {
   throw new InvalidDocumentCodeException(documentCode);
}
```

i.e. you need to actually *generate and throw* the exception based on the input. At some stage above that in the method call hierarchy you need to handle it e.g. (in pseudocode)

while (!done) {

```
   try {
      getInput();
      done = true;
   }
   catch (InvalidDocumentCodeException e)  {
      System.err.println("Not a valid code");
   }
```

}